# android studio, sort int array for memory game

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, random

I have a question and I hope that someone of you can help me.

I am trying to make my own Memory Game App in Android Studio.

I created an ImageButton Array (bArray) in which all buttons are stored. In the `oncreate` method, I got a for loop to give every ImageButton a random Tag.

With the help of these Tags I assign one image to every ImageButton, but I only want one Image to be assigned twice and not e.g. three times.

So I need to find that Tags, that are assigned more than twice and to replace them with other Tags.

I dont know how to do that. I hope that you can help me. If you need more Information please just let me know.

```
for(ImageButton b : bArray) {
    Random random = new Random();
    i_rndTag = random.nextInt(bilderArray.length);
    b.setTag(i_rndTag);
}
```

Comment: got lucky, i feel like writing a memory game app for dementia patients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

populate an array with 1 copy of each image reference (`imageArray`).  create another array (`indexUsageArray`) with the same number of items and store how many times said image has been used.  verify random index against usage array, if usage count equals 2, run randomizer again and verify until you have an index which has NOT been used twice.

```
    try {
        String TAG = "RandomGame";
        String[] imageArray =  {"bread.jpg","potatoe.jpg","eaters.jpg","earlobe.jpg","paintbrush.jpg"};
        int counterMax = imageArray.length;
        int[] indexUsageArray = new int[counterMax];
        // there are 2 copies of each image
        String[] imageToDisplayAtPosition = new String[2*counterMax];
        Random random;
        int randomIntTemp = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<counterMax;) { // only increase i AFTER completed attempt at randomization assignement
            random  = new Random();
            randomIntTemp = random.nextInt(2*counterMax);
            if (indexUsageArray[i] < 2) {
                //Log.w(TAG,"randomIntTemp:["+randomIntTemp+"] i:["+i+"] indexUsageArray[i]:["+indexUsageArray[i]+"] imageToDisplayAtPosition:["+imageToDisplayAtPosition[randomIntTemp]+"]");
                if (imageToDisplayAtPosition[randomIntTemp] ==  null) {
                    imageToDisplayAtPosition[randomIntTemp] = imageArray[i];
                    indexUsageArray[i]++;
                } // try another random position for same image
            } else { // assigned both positions, move to next image
                i++;
            }
        }
        Log.w(TAG,"Assignments");
        for (int j=0;j<2*counterMax;j++) {
            Log.w(TAG,"j:["+j+"] image:["+imageToDisplayAtPosition[j]+"]");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

which results in (for example):

> ```
> j:[0] image:[earlobe.jpg]
> j:[1] image:[eaters.jpg]
> j:[2] image:[potatoe.jpg]
> j:[3] image:[eaters.jpg]
> j:[4] image:[earlobe.jpg]
> j:[5] image:[bread.jpg]
> j:[6] image:[paintbrush.jpg]
> j:[7] image:[potatoe.jpg]
> j:[8] image:[paintbrush.jpg]
> j:[9] image:[bread.jpg]
> ```

Comment: I am sorry, but i think that i dont know what you mean. Could you please give me a code example of your solution?
I got that two Arrays, but what do i do next? How can i store how many times the image is assigned?

Comment: @DIvin93 there you go.  dont forget to show how thankful you are for my sunday kindness.

Comment: please consider posting your project as free source once you're done.  ;)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you use your own class:

```
class CustomImageButton {

 private int count;
 private ImageButton imageButton;
 private final int range = 32;

 public CustomImageButton() {
    imageButton = new ImageButton;
 }

 public void setTag() {
   if (count < 2) {
    imageButton.setTag(new Random().nextInt(range));
    count++;
  }
  return;
 }

}
```

Comment: dont you just hate downvoting drivebys?  if you feel SO strongly about an answer, the least you can do is say WHY you are downvoting.